# How to write javascript regular expression that matches a string and returns modified string

Tags: javascript

I am new in writing Regex in javascript. I have a use case that looks like this:

- *Input*: My {name} is {Rahul}
- *Output*: Array containing - **name** and **Rahul**.

I can write Regex to extract **{name}** and **{Rahul}** and then modify it. But is there a way that I search for **{name}** using Regex in the string but returns **name** in the output.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try both https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp and http://regexr.com/

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score -2):

You might have better luck using the split() method to just grab the last word since the word 'name' isn't changing, only the actual name value is.

```
var str = "My name is Rahul";

var res = str.split(" ");

var name = res[3];
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for an option that Regex itself would do this if possible.